My cursor in VS code is too wide like a block and it cannot change to a thin line again
So out of nowhere my cursor in VS code has become wide like a block. Its annoying to code with because the block overlaps on written code all the time.
I already went to settings, it is set to line, blinking, and the cursor width is 0. I tried changing it using json which had no effect either. I have searched it up many times and cannot find a solution to this.

first turn off Num Lock button, then press insert (Zero button), this will reset your cursor again to a thin line

Your cursor is in overwrite mode. Press the insert key once to revert this. (Based on the keyboard layout, you might need to press the Fn key at the same time.)

Okay that worked thanks
